# php: dynamically call overloadable function with an argument array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Question may be confusing...

the php `array_merge()` function takes an unlimited amount of arguments E.G.

```
array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4, $array5, $array6, $array7);
```

but what if I want to call this from within a function?

I have a `merge()` function that can be overloaded, and I want to do things to the array before concatenating them!

so how is array_merge called when I've got the array arguments in an array?

EXAMPLE

```
public function index() {

    $head = $this->_model->title("Index Page"); // returns array

    $nav = $this->_model->navigation(); // returns array

    $default = $this->_model->default_page(); // returns array

    $data = $this->merge($head, $nav, $default); // merge all arrays

    $this->loadView( 'view_admin', $data );
}

private function merge(){
    $args = func_get_args();

    // ... do stuff the the arrays ...

    return array_merge($args[0],$args[1],$args[2]);
}
```

As you can see, currently in my merge function is:

```
return array_merge($args[0],$args[1],$args[2]);
```

This is hardcoded in.

How do I dynamically call the array_merge() function???

maybe something like

```
array_merge(/* All Array args passed in */)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return call_user_func_array('array_merge', $args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use `call_user_func` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)
as:

```
return call_user_func("array_merge", $args);
```